# Set focus() back to contenteditable

Tags: contenteditable

I'm building a mini WYSIWYG editor with a modal window (Twitter Bootstrap) for entering image paths. The workflow is like this:

1. User is editing something in the contenteditable div and wants to insert an image
2. User clicks the image button, the modal window opens
3. User enters some URL into the input field and hit the enter key

Now I'm trying to `focus()` back to the contenteditable div. Unfortunately it seems not to be focussed, because things like `document.execCommand()` don't work.

In other words:

How can I bring back the focus() to the contenteditable div after being in an input field?

I have seen a couple of solutions for that, some with big scripts doing some `Range`/`Selection`-stuff, but I'm sure there is a much simpler solution for this...

Anyone?